# Using MUI V5 component in MUI V4 react app

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

We have a legacy react app which uses MUI v4.

I have created a react component as a package using MUI v5 & this package has to be used in the legacy react app.

When adding my react component into the app, the form fields are getting "squished" (label & input area overlap). Can anyone help in why this is happening & how to get this sorted?

This is how the component renders on its own

[image: On its own]

This is how the component renders inside the legacy app

[image: In the legacy app]

**Update** Package.json info added as requested

`package.json` of the component

```
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.45.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.18.9",
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.9",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.18.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.9",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.18.9",
    "@hookform/devtools": "^4.3.1",
    "@types/node": "^20.4.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.35.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.31.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.20.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "i18next": "^21.8.14",
    "jest": "^26.6.0",
    "jest-sonar-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "^11.18.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.63.5",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "webpack": "^5.87.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.3"
  }
```

`package.json` of the React App

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.7",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.9.0",  
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
    "@mui/material": "^5.0.3",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.11.12",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.0.1",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.29",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "base64url": "^3.0.1",
    "copy-to-clipboard": "^3.3.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "core-js-pure": "^3.1.4",
    "css-mediaquery": "^0.1.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.7",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "fast-xml-parser": "^4.0.7",
    "highcharts": "^9.0.1",
    "highcharts-react-official": "^3.0.0",
    "http-status-codes": "^2.2.0",
    "httpsnippet": "^2.0.0",
    "i18next": "^21.6.16",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.1.4",
    "jspdf": "^2.1.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.13",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "material-table": "1.69.0",
    "mobx": "^6.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.42",
    "node-rsa": "^1.1.1",
    "qs": "^6.9.4",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.6",
    "react-breadcrumbs-dynamic": "^1.2.1",
    "react-data-export": "^0.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^10.2.1",
    "react-ga": "^3.3.0",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "^2.1.0",
    "react-i18next": "^11.16.7",
    "react-idle-timer": "^4.6.4",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "^5.1.0",
    "react-jwt": "^1.1.2",
    "react-material-ui-carousel": "^3.4.2",
    "react-pdf": "^5.4.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-select-nested": "^1.0.5",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "react-standalone": "^0.3.2",
    "react-sticky": "^6.0.3",
    "react-syntax-highlighter": "^12.2.1",
    "react-through": "^1.1.4",
    "react-typist": "^2.0.5",
    "redoc": "^2.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "sass": "^1.63.6",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.2",
    "xml-formatter": "^2.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.8.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.5",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.23.2",
    "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^1.1.1",
    "jest-sonar-reporter": "^2.0.0"
  },
```

Comment: If you don't mind, please share your package.json file.

Comment: @VictorL. `package.json` info added

Comment: so do you mean that you have two difference package.json file in your project? If so, there are some compatibility issues in react and material-ui. If not, there are other problem such as CSS or props conflict, could you please provide minimal reproductive code?

Comment: I have a similar issue but other way around. Have a component library with MUI v4 and wanted to add that to a new project that uses MUI v5. If you got the answer to this question, I'd be very interested to hear about it